# Bipolar switch on UK standard wall sockets

Tags: socket

the company where I work would like to produce and market a type of wall socket with UK standard. I have seen that some models produce by our competitors are equipped with a bipolar switch, others are not. Is anyone aware of any standard or regulation prescribing that this bipolar switch is mandatory?
Furthermore, we would like to market a model with 2 USB charging sockets (type-A and type-C), so there would not be physically the space to insert a bipolar switch.
Thanks in advance for your comments,
Gischio

Comment: I thought all on-off switches could be classed as bipolar so, what do you really mean? Dual-pole? Dual-throw? Or do you mean two independent switches?

Comment: If you are planning to sell sockets in the UK, you need to purchase a copy of BS1363.  Without that, you will have no idea if your sockets are even legal to sell.

Comment: In the UK market wall sockets *invariably* have rocker switches (though normally single-pole not dual pole) on each socket. This includes wall sockets that incorporate USB outlets - other manufacturers certainly have no problem finding space for both switches and USB ports..

Comment: @Andyaka thanks for your comment. I'm referring to the switch which is commonly present on the UK socket, that can interrupt at the same time both Live and Neutral cables.